# JQuery - Hide/show option from previous selected dropdown

Tags: jquery, selectlist

I want to hide option from previous selected dropdown but my solution only works for two dropdown list.

This means that when I come to third dropdown list it will not display selected option from second dropdown list which is ok but it will display selected option from first one.

So, as I understand, methods I'm using overrides the last one that's why it not works.

Here is my select lists:

```
<select id="select1" 
        onchange="getSelectValue(this.value)" 
        asp-for="AssignedGroups.GroupMemberId1" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Agents,"Agent_Id","Agent_Id"))" 
        class="form-control">
    <option hidden selected></option>
</select>

<select id="select2" 
        onchange="getSelectValue2(this.value)" asp-
        for="AssignedGroups.GroupMemberId2"  
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Agents,"Agent_Id","Agent_Id"))"  
        class="form-control" >
    <option hidden selected></option>
</select>

<select id="select3" 
        onchange="getSelectValue3(this.value)" asp-
        for="AssignedGroups.GroupMemberId3" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Agents, "Agent_Id", "Agent_Id"))" 
        class="form-control">
    <option hidden selected></option>
</select>
```

And my script:
**strong text**

```
function getSelectValue(select1) {
            $("#select2 option[value='" + select1 + "']").hide();
            $("#select2 option[value!='" + select1 + "']").show();
            $("#select3 option[value='" + select1 + "']").hide();
            $("#select3 option[value!='" + select1 + "']").show();

    }

    function getSelectValue2(select2) {
        
            $("#select1 option[value='" + select2 + "']").hide();
            $("#select1 option[value!='" + select2 + "']").show();
            $("#select3 option[value='" + select2 + "']").hide();
            $("#select3 option[value!='" + select2 + "']").show();

    }

    function getSelectValue3(select3) {
        $("#select1 option[value='" + select3 + "']").hide();
        $("#select1 option[value!='" + select3 + "']").show();
        $("#select2 option[value='" + select3 + "']").hide();
        $("#select2 option[value!='" + select3 + "']").show();

        
    }
```

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a single function that handles unhiding and hiding of all options, then filters the other dropdowns' options based on all selected values. Here's the function/demo:

```js
function hideOthers() {
  // Get all selected values
  let selectedValues = $(".form-control option:selected").map(function() {
    if (this.value.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.value;
  });
  // Unhide all so we can hide the correct ones
  $("select.form-control option").removeAttr('hidden');

  // Filter out the selected values from dropdowns
  $(".form-control").each(function() {
    var selectElem = $(this);
    $.each(selectedValues, function(index, value) {
      // If the selected value from the array is from the applicable <select>, skip hiding
      if (selectElem.find("option:selected").val() !== value) {
        selectElem.find(`option[value="${value}"]`).attr('hidden', true);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" onchange="hideOthers()" class="form-control">
  <option hidden selected></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" onchange="hideOthers()" class="form-control">
  <option hidden selected></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select id="select3" onchange="hideOthers()" class="form-control">
  <option hidden selected></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```